# How to show file paths in Finder search result lists when searching by filename?

Tags: finder, ventura

I've got a complex folder tree that contains over a dozen instances of the same file. I want to see and compare where they all are, to see if there are any in unexpected locations, unexpected file sizes by location, etc.

I thought this would be easy to do by using Finder's search by filename, but there doesn't seem to be any way to include the file path in the search results:

[image]

I've got "Show path bar" enabled in View options, so I can see a sort of icon-heavy version of the path at the very bottom of the window if I select each one in turn:

[image]

...and I can also use the terminal to list path like `find . -name libc++_shared.so`:

[image]

...but what I really want is a way to view all the paths in a list, in Finder. Is it possible?

Finder has a lot of more "advanced" view options hidden away in system menus or behind keyboard shortcuts, I'm hoping there's one like this.

*This is on Ventura 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a).*

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer.  A workaround though would be selecting the results, pressing the option key and "copying xx items as pathnames", then past them into a text document, or such.

Comment: Are you prepared to look at alternative applications? E.g. HoudahSpot, File List Export or some of the Finder alternatives?

Comment: Personally, probably not, but it might help someone else with a similar problem, so feel free to post as an answer if there's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

[File List Export](https://www.gtrigonakis.com/filelistoexcel/) (from the Mac App Store) does exactly what you want by scanning all the files in a folder and its subfolders.

Open the app and choose a folder to scan. The results are shown like this:

[image]

There are about 60 columns, including the full Path for each file. Sorting can be on any column.

As well as using the results screens as is, you can export the results as a CSV  or Excel file for further processing.

Disclaimer: I am a user of this app, and have no other relationship with the developer.